# in org-mode, how to begin numbering at a certain heading depth?

Tags: org-mode

For HTML export, is there a way to instruct org-mode to BEGIN heading number at a certain heading depth? So that the top-level headings are NOT numbered?

So i.e. the export would look like this:

## The first top-level heading

### 1. Heading

#### 1.1 Heading

#### 1.2 Heading

### 2. Heading

#### 2.1 Heading

#### 2.2 Heading

## The second top-level heading

### 1. Heading

#### 1.1 Heading

#### 1.2 Heading

### 2. Heading

#### 2.1 Heading

#### 2.2 Heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default solution -- at least, currently -- to that problem.

However, you can quite easily solve this by a couple of CSS rules.